# Camera numpad "0" key not working

Tags: 3d-view, camera, shortcut

This only started happening recently. My <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> key won't enter the "Camera mode" when pressed anymore on the viewport. Does anyone know why this is happening? I am currently using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> as a result and works perfectly fine so I believe it is an issue with the numbers. This is happening on a Blender 3.2.

Comment: Are you sure that the camera is selected (its triangle must be orange), if not, select it and press Ctrl 0

Comment: Is "emulate numpad" turned on in settings?

Comment: Is Numpad 0 still in the key binding?

Comment: Hello, I have yet to try and turn on "emulate numpad" & make sure if the camera is selected with ctrl 0. I will send the results later on. Thanks for yalls help.

Comment: The issue has been resolved. "emulate numpad" was the issue being not active